# Nearby cycles of a constant $\Lambda$-sheaf

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, nearby-cycles

Let $X$ be a scheme over a henselian trait $S = (S,s,\eta)$. Let $\ell$ be a prime number which is invertible on $S$ and let $\Lambda := \mathbb Z_{\ell}/\ell^k\mathbb Z_{\ell}$ where $k\geq 1$. Let $\overline{\eta}$ be a geometric point of $S$ over $\eta$, and let $\overline s$ denote the associated geometric point over $s$. We have a short exact sequence
$$0 \to I \to \mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\eta}/\eta) \to \mathrm{Gal}(\overline s/s) \to 0$$
where $I$ denotes the inertia. There is a notion of nearby cycles $\mathrm R\Psi_{\eta} : D^+(X_{\eta},\Lambda) \to D^+(X_s \times_S \eta,\Lambda)$, where the target is the upper-bounded derived category of $\Lambda$-sheaves on $X_{\overline{s}}$ equipped with an action of $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\eta}/\eta)$ which is compatible with the action of $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline s/s)$ on $X_{\overline{s}}$ via the short exact sequence above (this is defined in SGA 7 XIII).
The nearby cycles functor is defined in the following way. Let $\overline S$ be the normalization of $S$ in $\kappa(\overline{\eta})$. Let $\overline X := X\times_S \overline S$ and write $X_{\overline s} \xrightarrow{\overline i} \overline X \xleftarrow{\overline j} X_{\overline{\eta}}$. Then for $K \in D^+(X_{\eta},\Lambda)$, we have
$$\mathrm R\Psi_{\eta}K := \overline{i}^*\mathrm R\overline{j}_{*}K_{\overline{\eta}}.$$

Let $M$ be a $\Lambda$-module, and let $\underline{M}_{\eta}$ (resp. $\underline{M}_{s}$) denote the associated constant sheaf on $X_{\eta}$ (resp. on $X_s$). Do we have an isomorphism
$$\mathrm R\Psi_{\eta}\underline{M}_{\eta} \simeq \mathrm R\Psi_{\eta}\Lambda \otimes^{L} \underline{M}_{\overline s}$$
in $D^+(X_s\times_s \eta,\Lambda)$, where $\underline{M}_{\overline s}$ is the pullback of $\underline{M}_{s}$ to $X_{\overline s}$?

Comment: I think this should be true because the nearby cycles functor has finite cohomological dimension. See [Lei Fu, Etale cohomology theory, 6.5.5 & 7.5.7].